# Can we use request method "POST" for getting flow status in apache nifi

Tags: post, apache-nifi

I am using GET method to get the current status of the nifi. When I tried to use POST method to get the status ,the remote server returned a 405 error. Please let me know is there any solution to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The status endpoint only accepts `GET` requests. Any other HTTP method will cause an error and return a 405 status code. Is there a reason you are trying to use `POST`? The documentation states that it only accepts `GET`.

```
GET /flow/status
Gets the current status of this NiFi
Request
consumes:
*/*
Response
produces:
application/json
Status Code Type    Description
200 ControllerStatusEntity  successful operation
400 string  NiFi was unable to complete the request because it was invalid. The request should not be retried without modification.
401 string  Client could not be authenticated.
403 string  Client is not authorized to make this request.
409 string  The request was valid but NiFi was not in the appropriate state to process it. Retrying the same request later may be successful.
Authorization
Read - /flow
```